# Fewer vertices vs. fewer fragmens

Tags: c++, opengl-es

Currently I'm implementing a string rendering algorithm that basically samples texels from a texture atlas with quads as underlying geometry. I have to choose between two approaches:

- Render each glyph of the string as individual quad. Every vertex has a position and the font atlas texture coordinate. The fragment shader samples the atlas and is otherwise trivial.
- Render the whole string as ONE quad. The vertex format has to be expanded by a little bookkeeping info (2 floats) and the fragment shader gets a couple of additional multiplications. There is a fragment overhead of ca. 10%.

Which is potentially more performant?

Comment: Why not try benchmarking both? What I could think of is you can lose some performance with the second approach because the quads can't be drawn in parallel.

Comment: My assumption was that a) The amount of vertex data sent to the gpu (which has to be done every frame) is lower (although I don't know if this counts for gles and shared memory architectures) and b) Fragments can still be processed in parallel, right?

Comment: With the second option, how do you lookup the correct texels in the fragment shader? If it introduces a dependent texture read then that can be a big performance penalty on many older OpenGLES devices. As a rule of thumb reducing fragment shader work is usually the way to go, but measuring is the only way to be sure.

Comment: It introduces one more texture read over the existing one. The device is gles 3.1 capable.

Comment: Btw does using a sampler array with branching introduce a dependent texture read? That means, I use if-else  clauses to choose one of several samplers to sample from?

Answer (score 0):

For most graphics content there is relatively little text on screen, so unless you are rendering thousands of character glyph per frame I wouldn't worry about it too much.

The one thing you will need to do is batch the glyph rendering into a small number of `glDraw*()` calls on the CPU-side; I've seen a lot of content render one glyph per draw which is insanely expensive - don't do that!

Comment: I already have it all in one draw call. I look at the perspective of rendering hundreds of strings with ten thousands of glyphs.

Comment: I suspect the only sensible answer is "benchmark it" on the platforms you care about running on. 10s of K glyphs, is 40s of K vertices, which will start to become a significant chunk of performance on some lower-end mobile platforms.